# not able to indent th & td elements within a table

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to indent the above subject elements because they are child rows of the entire table.

I can't use two separate tables because of the definition in my cshtml razor code which equates to specific child data from the table model.

Can anybody tell me how I can perform an indentation with the "TimeTrackingID" th element and the 'id' value td element underneath it where it would seem to belong to the parent row above it?

### Here is my CSHTML code

```
@model IEnumerable<YeagerTechDB.Models.Project>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Projects";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Projects with associated TimeTrackings</h2>

<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th align="right">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th align="right">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quote)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UpdatedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.Company)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category.CategoryDescription)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Priority.PriorityDescription)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status.StatusDescription)
        </th>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quote)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdatedDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.Email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.Company)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryDescription)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority.PriorityDescription)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status.StatusDescription)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "ProjectTimeTrackings", new { area = "Projects", id= item.ProjectID, name = item.Name })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" aria-hidden="true"></span>Create TimeTracking</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            if (item.TimeTrackings.Count > 0)
            {
                <tr style="margin-left:1em">
                    <th align="right" style="padding:3px">TimeTrackingID</th>
                    <th align="center" style=" padding:3px">StartDate</th>
                    <th align="center" style=" padding:3px">EndDate</th>
                </tr>
                foreach (var projTimeItem in item.TimeTrackings)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" style="padding:3px">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => projTimeItem.TimeTrackingID)
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding:3px">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => projTimeItem.StartDate)
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding:3px">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => projTimeItem.EndDate)
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding:3px">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "ProjectTimeTrackings", new { area = "Projects", id = item.ProjectID })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>Details</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is my image of the table.
Please use your favorite image viewer to copy the image here and paste it to your viewer to get a better picture.
[image]

Comment: Because your th & your td doesn't matched. You can use colspan to indent it nicely.

Comment: The colspans didn't do any indentations except to span the columns farther apart which I knew would happen. It didn't affect the indentation of the child row.

Comment: Actually, the colspan did work... I fixed the closing </tr> that was missing; I put an empty <th> & <td> with a colspan of 1. It indented the child row by 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

Try making width and height of main table as 100% - this will align all the columns in one row. 
All the columns as 8% width (100/14 -14 are total number of columns).

Set padding for th and td as 0px and margin as 0px.

Set word wrap property for all the columns as true.